# dacpac creation from Azure Synapse dedicated SQL Pool using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-synapse, dacpac

I have created the sql dacpac file from azure SQL database using Devops pipeline inbuilt task '**Azure SQL database deployment**'. Now I am trying to create dacpac file from azure synapse SQL Pool. but I didn't find any related task or PowerShell script to do the same.

can you please pour your valuable suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the same task for SQL Dedicated pool deployment as well. There is no separate task for it

My blogs for reference :
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/11/automated-deployment-of-azure-sql-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse-through-azure-devops-via-service-principal-part-1/
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/03/12/automated-deployment-of-azure-sql-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse-through-azure-devops-via-service-principal-part-2/

To create a DACPAC, in build pipeline you can leverage visual studio build task with latest version.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually my question was how to create dacpac file from Azure Synapse SQL pool. Deployment of dacapac will remain as what I did for SQL dacpac. Do you think the same sqlpackage.exe arguments can be used to create dacpac for azure synapse SQL pool?

Comment: To create a DACPAC, in build pipeline you can leverage visual studio build task with latest version. I have updated my answer above.
But yes, the same arguments via cmd line in case of self agent can run

Comment: Thanks. I will try the same arguments to see if I would be able to use it to generate the dacpac. Appreciate the response.

Comment: I tried the same SqlPackage arguments to generate the dacpac file from Azure Synapse SQL Pool and it worked for me. Thank you so much for providing your inputs.

Comment: Glad, I could help :)
Can you please upvote and mark it as answer as it is beneficial for other community members as well